# Distribution enterprise for java artifacts?

Tags: java, bintray, jcenter

I was wondering if there is a distribution management entity for java based artifacts, very similar to the way RHEL (or the like) distributes the linux based artifacts. Some of the features that were of interest were:

- Source code for the artifacts (should the open source project hosting website goes away)
- Security updates related alerts (like if the previous distribution version used a version of struts that is known to have security vulnerabilities, we should get a notice of it proactively)
- Secure SSL connections (I know jcenter bintray provides this rather than the non-SSL to maven central)
- Licensing related meta-data (because not all maven artifacts use the license-maven-plugin)
- Possible whitelisting of artifacts that are approved for use

I am not very sure myself if this can be achieved outside of a repo manager itself, and was hoping that someone might point out the similiarities between this and RHEL for the OS related modules that have similar security updates related alerts. I might be completely off, and would appreciate if someone can point out how these concerns are addressed in the java world.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to be already aware about the maven repo manager software. Aside from security alerts, aren't your features already covered there? And indeed, that is the normal way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [Bintray](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/index.html).

Bintray is a cloud platform that gives you full control over how you publish, store, promote, and distribute software.

As the most advanced platform for distributing software, Bintray offers:

- Private repositories with fine-grained access control.
- 100% automation.
- Stats and logs.
- Download speed and reliability.

You can read more details about [Bintray features](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/intro/intro_mainfeatures.html).

For security alerts you should use the [JFrog-Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) and [configure it with the JFrog-Xray](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/XRAY/Configuring+Xray). The Xray product allows to add watchers and sign webhooks specific to the configuration you define. You can [start your free trial](https://www.jfrog.com/xray/free-trial/).

Good luck.

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [[image]bintray](/questions/tagged/bintray) and [[image]artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory) and [xray](/questions/tagged/xray), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6800023/rotemy?tab=profile) for details and links.</sup>

Comment: Since OP explicitly asked for security alerts, are those offered by bintray as well? Because that's the one thing I haven't seen with java artifacts, and don't really know how that would work, either.

Comment: I added changes in the answer so you can have the links to the relevant pages can help you. I hope it helps.